# Retrieve the computer's charging status & current battery level

Tags: excel, vba, battery, batterylevel, system-properties

I needed a **VBA** procedure to retrieve the system's **current battery charge level and charging status**.

I was surprised not to find anything on Stack Overflow, and I eventually figured it out, so I'll share the code here as a Q+A.

Comment: There's a surprising amount of overlap between this question and that one concerning timezones. While WinAPI and structs are difficult subjects, imo it's not sensible to have a Q&A here for all the different things you can do with it (and I think getting the battery status is very niche, and rarely necessary in a VBA application).

Comment: @Erik - There's a ton of rarely-used methods documented on this site, and I believe that was one of [so]'s original goals. The two you mentioned are *far* from related, as it's unlikely that someone's going to search for "Time Zones" when seeking help with Battery Status. Indeed there are plenty more "niche" methods yet to be documented; if you have time to lump them all together in the form of a single all-enveloping canonical, that would be a great addition. In this case I had a need, there was no existing answer, so I Q+A'd as [Atwood encouraged](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its).

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I'm not against self-answering. I'm just against self-answering things where I believe there's no real need to have this knowledge here. And I'm more for a blog somewhere (or maybe even a Q&A on SO, though it might be too broad) about how to call WinAPI functions in VBA than sharing an implementation for a lot of individual WinAPI functions.

Comment: I like the niche questions and answers, the aim is to cover everything on SO. Plus I hadn't seen this idea anywhere else.

Comment: The main problem I have with this approach is that you're giving people fish without explaining to them how to fish. Yes, it's useful if you just want a fish, but explaining the underlying techniques is way more useful than just sharing an example. In the end, you're more likely to limit knowledge than to spread it this way. It's especially annoying if you go sharing different Q&A's that essentially boil down to the same problem: calling WinAPI functions and interpreting the results.

Comment: If someone has answered their own question that doesn't stop anyone else answering on it. Anyone else could add more detail on how this works if they need to. I don't see how this would limit knowledge.

Comment: It limits knowledge in the way that you could explain how to use these WinAPI functions in VBA, but instead of doing that, it shares a ready-to-use example with 0 explanation of how the type is declared or how the code is constructed, asides from non-explanations like `'estimate FullLifeTime:` or even `'show some information`. I mean, the answer is just a code dump + 3 off-site links, if you want to know what's actually happening, it offers little, and if you want to apply the same technique to a different problem, it offers nothing. This means a user hasn't learnt how to do anything himself.

Comment: Answering one's own question is not only [allowed](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/05/22/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/), it's actually [encouraged](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).  Was my question/answer up to *your* standards?  That's irrelevant.  The beauty of a site like this is that it is not about appealing to one user's needs, and thus, the "community moderation" aspect allows "more useful" answers to rise to the top. If you find my posts don't fit your needs, by all means, downvote - however, an opinionated narrative is of no benefit.

Comment: Also, while I see benefit to [canonical](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291992/what-is-a-canonical-question-answer-and-what-is-their-purpose) posts (something many users dislike), this is not one. I didn't intend to provide a thorough study into the inner workings of Windows API's, not cover everything that they are capable of. However, I think a post like that would be of great benefit, and I encourage you to put one together. We both post solid information & examples; unfortunately I don't have time to make every post an all-encompassing single documentative source on the subject.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetSystemPowerStatus Lib "kernel32" (lpSystemPowerStatus As SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS) As LongPtr

Private Type SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS
    ACLineStatus As Byte
    BatteryFlag As Byte
    BatteryLifePercent As Byte
    SystemStatusFlag As Byte
    BatteryLifeTime As Long
    BatteryFullLifeTime As Long
End Type


Public Sub getBatteryStatus() 'batt info to immediate window
    
    Dim SPS As SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS
    GetSystemPowerStatus SPS 'get system batt power status
    
    With SPS
        Debug.Print "Battery Life:  ", ;
        Select Case .BatteryLifePercent
            Case 255:   Debug.Print "Unknown"
            Case Else:  Debug.Print .BatteryLifePercent & "%"
        End Select
        
        Debug.Print "Battery Life Time: ", ;
        Select Case .BatteryLifeTime
            Case -1:    Debug.Print "Charging"
            Case Else
                Debug.Print Int(.BatteryLifeTime / 60) & "min / ";
                Select Case .BatteryFullLifeTime
                    Case -1
                        If .BatteryLifePercent = 0 Then
                            Debug.Print "Unknown"
                        Else 'estimate FullLifeTime:
                            Debug.Print "~" & Int(.BatteryLifeTime / .BatteryLifePercent * 5 / 3) & "min"
                        End If
                    Case Else
                        Debug.Print .BatteryFullLifeTime & "sec"
                End Select
        End Select

        Debug.Print "AC power status: ", ;
        Select Case .ACLineStatus 'show some information
            Case 0:     Debug.Print "Offline"
            Case 1:     Debug.Print "OnLine"
            Case Else:  Debug.Print "Unknown"
        End Select
        
        Debug.Print "Battery charge status: ", ;
        Select Case .BatteryFlag
            Case 0:     Debug.Print "Not Charging (33-66%)"
            Case 1:     Debug.Print "High (>66%)"
            Case 2:     Debug.Print "Low (<33%)"
            Case 4:     Debug.Print "Critical (<5%)"
            Case 8:     Debug.Print "Charging"
            Case 1 + 8: Debug.Print "High (>66%)- Charging"
            Case 2 + 8: Debug.Print "Low (<33%) - Charging"
            Case 4 + 8: Debug.Print "Critical (<5%) - Charging"
            Case 128:   Debug.Print "No System Battery"
            Case 255:   Debug.Print "Unknown Status"
        End Select
    
        Debug.Print "Battery saver: ", ;
        Select Case .SystemStatusFlag
            Case 0:     Debug.Print "Off"
            Case 1:     Debug.Print "On (Save energy where possible)" 'Windows 10 only
        End Select

    End With
End Sub
```

---

### More Information:

- MSDN : [**GetSystemPowerStatus function**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa372693.aspx) (Windows)
- MSDN : [**SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS structure**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa373232.aspx)
- MSDN : [**Battery Saver**](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/design/component-guidelines/battery-saver)

Comment: Rather unrelated, I didn't know you could do `Debug.Print "foo ";` and a second code line `Debug.Print "bar"` to get the result in a single line. Cool!

Comment: @Andre -  Yeah it's handy; just keep in mind line continuation `;` only works with the debug (immediate) window at the end of a line. (Shortcut to open immediate window from VBA = CTRL+G)....  You can use `;` mid-string-only elsewhere, where it acts like a `&`, like `myString = "abc"l "def"`.

Comment: myString = "abc"l "def"    ?

Comment: Would recommend to adapt code for using 64b/32b via conditional compiling via `#If VBA7 Then` and
    `Declare PtrSafe Function GetSystemPowerStatus ...`, no other changes as no long pointers needed :-) @ashleedawg